# Typescript lib not respected

Tags: typescript

My tsconfig looks like this

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES5",
    "lib": [
        "DOM",
        "ES5"
    ],
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "typeRoots": ["src/types"],
    "types": [
        "animejs",
        "hammerjs",
        "jasmine",
        "node"
    ]
}
```

}

Now I would expect a failure to arise when using code such as

```
Object.values({'a': 1});
```

Given that Object.values is not supported by ES5 I'd expect a compile error however this is simply passed through with no errors and compiles as if no errors are found.

Versions

```
"ts-loader": "~8.1.0",
"tslib": "~2.2.0",
"typescript": "~4.2.4",
```

I'm not sure I am missing anything?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've just tested, and TS compile the error correctly.
https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-forked-fivqm?file=/index.ts

Comment: I found the reason behind this where @types/nodes brings in ES7 of Object.keys